# sumifs + offset function

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I´m stuck trying to build this excel function:

I have this matrix [(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyblw.jpg) with quarter year sums and I want it to sum up to the month I indicate in the cell next to "Month", excluding all the quarteryear sums. So far my Formula, as an array:

```
={SUM(SUMIFS(($Q20:OFFSET($Q20;0;$S$16-1));R19:AG19;AD16:AG16))}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could jsut sum up the whole range and devide the result by 2, or would you like to use the formula in the future, also when there are no Quarter-Values jet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Data is in A1:Q2 [image: like this]

Then you could either use this in Q2:

```
=SUM(A2:P2)/2
```

if you only want to calculate the sum for the whole year, or like this, if you also watn to use the formula during the year:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:P2,--(MOD(COLUMN($A:$P),4)<>0))
```

(Auf deutsch dann so:

```
=SUMMENPRODUKT(A2:P2;--(REST(SPALTE($A:$P);4)<>0))
```

)

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your answer. I´m not sure this is what I am looking for, but maybe that´s because I don´t understand the formula. What is the order here?         ,--(MOD(COLUMN($A:$P),4)<>0))

Comment: @Urumita Basicly what it does is the following: Column(x) returns the coloumn of the cell x, so 1 for Column A, 2 for Column B and so on. Now we check if the Column number is devidable by 4 (MOD(y,4)), since every 4th element will be the quarter-Value. So MOD(y,4)<>0 returns TRUE if COLUMN(x) is NOT devidable by 4. the "--" infront transforms Boolean Values (TRUE and FALSE) into numerical Values (True = 1 and False = 0). Then we take the Sumproduct of the resulting array consisting of 1's and 0's with the corresponding Values.

Comment: @Urumita If you could maybe explain, in more detail, what exactly you want to achieve and how your data is stored, that would make it easier, to help you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So basically in the array we are multiplying all the Quarters by 0 and all the months by 1. And the data has to be in A1:Q2 for it to work because of columns(x). Thanks for the tip. Viele Grüße!

Comment: Exactly. If your Data is somehwhere else You have to adjust the A2:P2 part accordingly, but leave the $A:$P part UNCHANGED. Hoffe es hilft!